# How to terminate unused transformer pins?

Tags: transformer, wiring, switching-regulator

What is the correct way to terminate/wire these unused transformer pins? Do they get tied to GND?

[image]

Comment: Gosh no, that would cause the [750311307](https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/750311307.pdf) to stop working. You could add another schottky rectifier and cap and use the voltage 1-2 generates as another (lower voltage) supply source. Traditionally this "aux winding" is used to power other parts of the circuitry.

Comment: What if I have no use for it?

Comment: I'm wondering if the transformer would run a bit cooler with both primaries in parallel. Anyone got a reason not to do that?

Comment: @Transistor would that not change the winding ratio?

Comment: @circuit_noob533 No it would not change the ratio. It would be like having the same number of turns with thicker wire. Transformers with multiple configurations have wiring diagrams that instruct you to wire them that way for configurations where the extra turns (via putting coils in series) are not needed.

Comment: @circuit: It would be like a mains transformer with 120 + 120 V windings. Wire them in series for 240 V and in parallel for 120 V.

Comment: @DKNguyen Are there any consequences for doing this? Also, it would be a (3+2) and (4+1) configuration right?

Comment: @circuit_noob533 Only good ones as far as I know, except requiring two more connections. Dot to dot since phasing needs to be the same. 3 connected to 2 and 1 connected to 4. Otherwise core flux just cancels.

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you explain in more detail what you mean by Dot to dot?

Comment: @circuit_noob533 Do you see those dots on the transformer pins indicating polarity?

Comment: yes. I think I understand now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't do anything with them, they are fine if they are floating and left open. If you're worried about a charge developing on the coil (which probably won't happen), you could tie one end to ground. Tying both ends to ground would result in a short and a considerable loss in energy.